# How do I perform a reverse depth below horizon study in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, viewshed, visibility

Using the visibility plugin for QGIS you can calculate the depth below horizon that targets (effectively individual pixels from the supplied DEM) appear to a single observer.

I would like to perform the reverse study - how high would my single observer point need to be visible at each of the targets?

From playing with binary viewsheds at different observer heights, it appears that the depth below horizon for a target is not the same as the depth below horizon for the observer for the same test.